# How to pass array of array (list of list) to view in play framework 2.x?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have been trying it for sometime and I have to create view for complex frontend application. This looks like I am able to send array list like:

In Controller :

```
ArrayList<String> cname = new ArrayList<>();
cname.add("akshay");
cname.add("david");
```

And in View :

```
@(cname: List[String])
```

But, now I have to create an array of this array. This could be other data structure as well like List, but for now I have to pass an array of array, which looks like :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

What type should be view then ? Below is not working :

```
@(cname : List[List[String]])
```

Any reference to tutorial/guide for such arrays for future reference would be much helpful.

Edit :

I need to pass ArrayList of ArrayList. The program in question is :

```
while(rs.next())
        {
            cname = rs.getString("customername");
            cmobile = rs.getString("customermobile");
            amount = rs.getString("billamount");

            namearr.add(cname);
            mobilearr.add(cmobile);
            amountarr.add(amount);

        }
        rowsArray.add(mobilearr);
        rowsArray.add(namearr);
        rowsArray.add(amountarr);
```

And I have to send rowsArray to front. I know using this kind of queries is abuse of Play Framework, but in this case, I had to go as native as possible. Is there any otherway I can send such data to frontend except JPA ? Is it possible that I create a class with these arrays and then in my controller create array of objects and send it to view ?

Comment: Can u answer this please

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433509/populating-drop-down-with-the-values-from-database-in-play-frame-work/29434643#29434643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the fully qualified class names since Scala has its own list type that shadows the Java list or is not imported automatically.

Use

```
@(cname : java.util.List[java.util.List[String]])
```

for

```
List<List<String>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
@(cname : java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[String]])
```

for

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

But the code could be more cleaner if you use types (new classes) for your data.

Comment: so this should be applied for Collections as well.

Answer (score 0):

`List` references to the scala type : `List` and not the java super type `java.util.List`. I have never used the Java version of Playframework but you should try to pass : `ArrayList[ArrayList[String]]`.